# Random Number generation

Tags: statistics, random-variables

I need to find a method to solve this problem:

give a method for generating a random variable having distribution function

$$F(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x + x^2) \hspace{1cm} 0 < x < 1$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate $U$ a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$ and then set $$X=\frac{-1+\sqrt{8U+1}}{2}$$ $X$ is a random draw from $F$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** One method consists of finding $f\colon[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ such that $F(f(t))=t$ for all $t\in[0,1]$. Then $f(X)$ has the required distribution if $X$ is unifomly distributed on $[0,1]$.